# I can't use ufw on WSL-Ubuntu

Tags: security, firewall, ufw, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use Windows 10 home (build 17134.471) with WSL-Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial).

I executed `apt update -y && ufw --force enable` and got the following trace (I don't know what it means - maybe some kernel functions missing thus some failed syscalls).

Is there any way to use WSL-Ubuntu as for today anyway?

### Trace:

```
ERROR: problem running ufw-init
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.4.0-17134-Microsoft/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module nf_conntrack_ftp not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-17134-Microsoft
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.4.0-17134-Microsoft/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module nf_nat_ftp not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-17134-Microsoft
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.4.0-17134-Microsoft/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module nf_conntrack_netbios_ns not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-17134-Microsoft
iptables-restore v1.6.0: iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'filter'

Error occurred at line: 1
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
iptables-restore v1.6.0: iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'filter'

Error occurred at line: 1
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
iptables-restore v1.6.0: iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'filter'

Error occurred at line: 1
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
iptables-restore v1.6.0: iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'filter'

Error occurred at line: 1
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
iptables-restore v1.6.0: iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'filter'

Error occurred at line: 1
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
iptables-restore v1.6.0: iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'filter'

Error occurred at line: 12
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
iptables-restore v1.6.0: iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'filter'

Error occurred at line: 12
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
iptables-restore v1.6.0: iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'filter'

Error occurred at line: 1
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
iptables-restore v1.6.0: iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'filter'

Error occurred at line: 1
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
iptables-restore v1.6.0: iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'filter'

Error occurred at line: 1
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.

Problem loading ipv6 (skipping)
Problem running '/etc/ufw/before.rules'
Problem running '/etc/ufw/after.rules'
Problem running '/etc/ufw/user.rules'
```

Comment: Same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66018516/wsl2-cannot-enable-ufw

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you don't have a Linux kernel.

`ufw` is a frontend for [`netfilter`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter). Netfilter is the Linux Kernels support for filtering IP packets. Windows has a [different mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Firewall), commonly named Windows Firewall.

`ufw` only supports netfilter, not Windows Firewall or other IP filtering technologies. It thus only works on systems with a Linux kernel.

The man page mentions this:

> ```
> This  program  is for managing a Linux firewall and aims to provide an
> easy to use interface for the user.
> ```

Some tools are really not portable to different platforms. This includes tools that, like `ufw`, attempts to interface the operating system kernel.

Comment: Taken from wiki.ubuntu.com: WSL2 features a Linux kernel running inside Windows 10 and is built on the core technology of Hyper-V to provide better Linux application support and improved file performance . I use WSL2 and cannot access internet since installing `ufw`. Do I have to uninstall `ufw` and reboot?

Comment: @Timo Just disable it I think? sudo ufw disable