# probleme running ufw on Ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: 20.04, iptables, firewall, ufw

I'm new to Ubuntu and to try it out I've installed the Ubuntu app from Microsoft store and running it on my windows 10 laptop, I tried to enable the UFW but I got this:

```
:~$ sudo ufw enable

ERROR: problem running ufw-init
iptables-restore v1.8.4 (legacy): iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'filter'

Error occurred at line: 1
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
iptables-restore v1.8.4 (legacy): iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'filter'

Error occurred at line: 1
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
iptables-restore v1.8.4 (legacy): iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'filter'

Error occurred at line: 1
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
iptables-restore v1.8.4 (legacy): iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'filter'

Error occurred at line: 1
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
iptables-restore v1.8.4 (legacy): iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'filter'

Error occurred at line: 1
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
iptables-restore v1.8.4 (legacy): iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'filter'

Error occurred at line: 12
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
iptables-restore v1.8.4 (legacy): iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'filter'

Error occurred at line: 12
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
iptables-restore v1.8.4 (legacy): iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'filter'

Error occurred at line: 1
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
iptables-restore v1.8.4 (legacy): iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'filter'

Error occurred at line: 1
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
iptables-restore v1.8.4 (legacy): iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'filter'

Error occurred at line: 1
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.

Problem loading ipv6 (skipping)
Problem running '/etc/ufw/before.rules'
Problem running '/etc/ufw/after.rules'
Problem running '/etc/ufw/user.rules'
```

since I'm really new to this, I don't know anything about iptables, filters and initialization or if it's just because it's on my Windows laptop. I already updated and upgraded everything with;

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and tried the command while rooted, didn't work. If you need any info, I will happily give it to you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you installed Ubuntu from the Microsoft Store?  Normally you can install a try with the ubuntu software. UFW is the normal firewall for Ubuntu. See  https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop and after booting with this iso file answer that you will try Ubuntu, not install.

Comment: reply to Julien Chau:
don't you need a vmware for that?

Comment: after you installed the app, did you run `sudo apt update` then sudo apt upgrade`? Even so, I still get some different errors trying to enable ufw on the MS Ubuntu app. I assume it is because it is running on WSL under windows.

Comment: reply to Doug Smythies:
yes i did and after the error. I also think that you are right it is about the MS app

Comment: I think the OP is using WSL2 version of Ubuntu within Windows. Now WSL2 is available at the Microsoft store.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't use ufw on WSL-Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1100739/i-cant-use-ufw-on-wsl-ubuntu)

Comment: @user68186 Thanks but I think I'm going to do what Julien chau said and install it and try it to see if i want a dual boot

Comment: Best of luck! The Ubuntu app in the Microsoft store is also called Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). It is similar to a virtual machine, but not quite. You get "almost" a full Linux system, but some things are not included. It is meant meant for doing some quick things using Linux without leaving Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just download the latest  Ubuntu version (https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and install it on a boot-able pen-drive or USB stick.
Just boot with this pen-drive, and then make the choice "try" or "install".  Follow the instruction.  By "trying" you can see if you want this system or not. If yes, you can install it in dual boot with the same installation pen-drive. Make your choice. But before installation make separate partitions on your hard disk.

Comment: thanks you very much for your explanation, it helps, but then, what is the Ubuntu app from MS even about?

Comment: nothing.  Self protecting.

Comment: ooooooh okok, thanks